# How Zookeper Authorization works?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am new to Zookeper and am wondering, I understand Zookeper can be used as configuration storage, and considering that what if I have one client of Zookeeper should not have access to certain configurations? How do I restrict that access?

Scenario: I want to use it as a configuration service, from where my application retrieves its configurations, database endpoint lists etc. Can I do that with Zookeper ? If I can how do I restrict access, so one application doesn't access configurations from another?

Answer (score 0):

ZooKeeper is a distributed co-ordination service to manage large set of hosts. Co-ordinating and managing a service in a distributed environment is a complicated process. ZooKeeper solves this issue with its simple architecture and API. ZooKeeper allows developers to focus on core application logic without worrying about the distributed nature of the application.

The ZooKeeper framework was originally built at “Yahoo!” for accessing their applications in an easy and robust manner. Later, Apache ZooKeeper became a standard for organized service used by Hadoop, HBase, and other distributed frameworks. For example, Apache HBase uses ZooKeeper to track the status of distributed data.

It's not a key-value storage

Comment: I want to use it as a configuration service, from where my application retrieves its configurations, database endpoint lists etc. Can I do that with Zookeper ? If I can how do I restrict access, so one application don't access configurations from another?

Comment: Could you please provide the requirement as your original question and this comment varies.